# js nav to remain opened when on visited link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Again using this, the best place on the net, to try and resolve a question of a poor designer with extremely limited developer skills;

I have this js nav bar which I need to remain opened once I click on one of the links within the dropdown link. It's hard for me to explain but I'm sure once you see it you'll understand what I mean:

```
<div id="Nav">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="historia.html">Historia</a></li>
              <li><a href="quienes.html">Qui&eacute;nes</a></li>
              </ul>
                <ul id="nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Galer&iacute;a</a>
                        <ul class="SubLinks">
                            <li><a href="proyecto1.html">Proyecto1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="proyecto2.html">Proyecto2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="proyecto3.html">Proyecto3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
  // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
  $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
  $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

  // open our new menu and add the open class
  $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
  $(this).addClass("open");
}

else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
  $(this).removeClass("open");
  $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
}
});
});
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Thanks for your help pal!!! I didn't manage to make that one work but I used it for another website and never managed to make it work. The idea is that when you click on the top link and drops down the other three links, it stays opened once you clicked on one of those three, for example, Historia.

http://jsfiddle.net/NQwxr/

Thanks dude

Comment: I had to do this exact thing for a Wordpress site. Same thing as yours, show a hidden menu items (submenu) and then once you click on a menu item to the next page, the menu is still open. This is the code I used: `$('.current-menu-ancestor > a').parent().addClass('over');` You would need to change the `current-menu-ancestor` and `class` to suit your needs. That worked for me. I'm not sure how your site is set up though (dynamic content). Hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I haven't been able to make it work but it's just cause I don't even know what to do with it... :( Not your fault obviously, I'm sure the line you gave me works perfect but, would you add it to the current .js? would you stick it in the html? How do I tell the code to do it just on the links mentioned?

Comment: Hey @GonzaloFernandez, you want to jump over chat to clarify what you need?

Comment: You would stick it right after `$(document).ready(function(){` Telling it to work on just the links mentioned is where you would need to update the CSS selectors in the code I provided. You are basically adding a class to the parent of the sub menu that tells the parent to stay extended (or open).

Comment: Hi leonid, that'd be great man, thanks! How does that work? do you invite me or something? disinfor, thanks for your help again man but I'm too useless for this... :( :( :(